# Docker Container for Custom Python Setup to Run Tests

Tags: python, docker

I'm new to using docker, and I was wondering how I could create a docker image for others to use to replicate the exact same setup I have for python when testing code. Currently what I've done is I created a docker image with the dockerfile below:

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

where the requirements text file contains the libraries and the versions I am using. I then ran this image on my local machine, and things looked good, so I pushed this image to a public repository on my docker hub account, so other people could pull it. This makes sense so far, but I'm still a little confused what to do next. If someone wants to test a python script on their local machine using my configuration what exactly would they do? I think they would pull my image from docker hub and then create a container from this image on their local machine. However, I tried this on my machine, testing a python file that runs and saves a file, and it's not really working how I anticipated. I can make a python file and put it in WORKDIR and have it run, but I think that's all it does. I'd really like to be able to navigate the container to find the file the python program created and then save it back on my local machine. Is there any way to do this, and am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Just as a side note, you could as well look into virtual environments (if you haven't already) like https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html. Everyone who receives your requirements file could install them into the venv and would have the very same environment (except python version, but for that you could look in e.g. conda which would be the next step after venv https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html).

Comment: @nyyrikki Yeah virtual environments are what I was using before, figured docker would be easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can execute bash in the container and check the files created inside of the container. Or you can share a volume between host and container. Such that you can check the files created in your host machine. Check this link, it might be helpful for you :-)
[Volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Comment: I tried executing bash in the container and I think that's what I was looking for. Now how exactly would I move the files that I created in the container to my local machine? Would I have to use volumes?

Comment: It seems like I can do this with docker cp, so what would the advantage of using volumes here be?

Comment: well, I don't see any advantage in technicality but in terms of practicality, I usually prefer mounting a volume to my host machine such that I can use my host machine's utilities(like vim, cat, or any other Linux utilities) on the shared files.

Comment: i think the other advantage is that, if you mount a volume then there will be less I/O operation as well. If the generated files in the container are too big in size then it might take a while to copy all of the files to the host machine. Hope it helped ;) mark my answer correct if i have answered your quesiton